# Gantt chart is not displayed for Project Tasks view in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, gantt-chart

I set up a default Project Tasks view in Sharepoint 2010. However, the default view, which is supposed to be a Gantt chart, doesn't show up. The other views (e.g. All Tasks, Active Tasks) are working correctly. This is on IE7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely happening due to a custom master page. See [this related post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/4ca640b4-3aae-4ddb-af37-a786d462b454/). The Gantt view requires the following div to be on the page in order to render the chart:

```
<div id="s4-workspace">
```

Check your custom master page to ensure this id has not been removed or changed.

Comment: Issue may be due to bootstrap overriding the existing css of gantt chart.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a problem with the CSS framework that we use to create the master page. With Bootstrap, there is a border-box style that can cause the chart from not displaying.

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

You can override that style to content-box instead. The challenge is to apply the style only to that element, so it does not affect other elements on the layout.

```
div[style$="border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171);"]
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

More detail can be found here: http://www.ozkary.com/2017/04/sharepoint-gantt-chart-hidden-bootstrap-master-page.html

Answer (score 0):

Below code resolved my problem:

```
div[id="ctl00_ctl44_g_f2bc7dff_3c34_41d6_b01a_c68e3baba6cc_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_rightpane"] {
float: inherit !important;
width: auto !important;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
box-sizing: content-box !important;}
```

Here "ctl00_ctl44_g_f2bc7dff_3c34_41d6_b01a_c68e3baba6cc_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_rightpane" is div id containing Gannt Chart view, so anyone using above code needs to be change this id.